# Change Symbol Size and Color for Multiple Feature Classes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, symbology

I need to expediently make an identical change to the symbol size and color of multiple feature classes. This can be done for layer transparency through a script such as:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.name == 'FC1' or 'FC2':
        if lyr.supports('TRANSPARENCY'):
            transparency = str(lyr.transparency)
            lyr.transparency = 45
```

But as far as I know, the color, size, and symbol type characteristics are not as easy to access and change. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can't change color or symbol size for layers directly using `arcpy`. Instead you'd create a layer with the desired symbology and save it as a `.lyr` file.

[image]

You can then use [Apply Symbology From Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm) on the layer you wish to alter.

Comment: I only want to change the color and size, but not the other components of the symbol. I understand a lyr file will changed the symbol in its entirety.